# Delete gameObject before the end of the frame

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two gameObjects really close to each others (let's call them A and B), an other one is coming with a certain speed (let it be C). And what I want is: that the object C delete itself and at the same time it delete the object A which it is colliding with.
I am using the onTriggerEnter function with the Delete() method to do it but unfortunatly this delete both gameObjects at the end of the frame. And within this very short time (collision -> delete) the object C which is moving can collide with the object B
So do anyone have a solution to delete the object C which is moving before it collides with the object B?

Comment: Why do you want the gameObject to be deleted this early? Is it because of physics being applied to B that are undesirable?

Comment: If the object C collides with the B the game ends and the purpose of the object A is to "protect" the object B

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options available to you.

The first, and most drastic, is to use `DestroyImmediate`. The documents [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html) describe why it might be used, but also warn against its use in general, unless you have a specific reason.

Another option would be to change the Layer of the object, so that the collision of C won't happen during the next FixedUpdate. That should be applied straight away, and stop your objects from colliding. To accomplish this, you'll have to make sure you have a new Layer, and in your physics ( or physics2D ) settings, you'll need to make sure that the layer Object C is on doesn't collide with the new Layer. You can find more about the collision matrix [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) at the Unity Docs.

A quick code example might look something like this:

```cs
    public LayerMask noCollisionLayer;
    public GameObject ObjectB;

    private void OnCollisionEnter ( Collision other )
    {
        ObjectB.layer = noCollisionLayer;
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your option and everything seems to work now thank you!